# How can I build a system of ODEs with ODEINT to meet the figure from literature?

Tags: python, odeint

With ODEINT, I am trying to configure the methane conversion over the height of a reactor. However, the figure my script produces is far from the figure from the literature. The value directly jumps to a number close to the maximum conversion. The approach is based on the [following research](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338225752_Coupled_hydrodynamic_and_kinetic_model_of_liquid_metal_bubble_reactor_for_hydrogen_production_by_noncatalytic_thermal_decomposition_of_methane).

To confirm I did the coding right, I set the superficial velocity (Jg), gas holdup (GH), and pressure (P) more or less constant in the range of the results from the research.

Can someone identify what leads to the difference between my figure and the figure from the literature??

My current code looks as followed:

```python
def odes(Initial,l): 
    MC = Initial[0]
    P  = Initial[1] #in bar multiply with 101325 to make Pa 
    JG = Initial[2] 
    GH = Initial[3]
    
    #Fixed constants
    R=8.314
    g=9.81
    
    #variable constants
    feed= 2544 #mol/s
    T=1100 #Temperature
    T=T+273.15
    L=14.3 #Length
    D=3.5 #Diameter
    
    #superficial flow
    JG = 0
    
    #gas_holdup
    GH = -(0.241-0.32)/L
    #GH=0.267
    
    #Pressure
    dPdl  = -(57.8-51.5)/L
    
    #Methane conversion constants
    n=1.0809
    k0=1.4676e10 #or 1.4676e4 research states two numbers
    Ea=284948
    k=k0*np.exp(-Ea/(R*T))
    Kc=(101325/(R*T))*np.exp(13.2714-(91204.6/(R*T)))
    
    dMCdl = ((k/feed)*(((1-MC)/(1+MC)*((P*101325)/R*T))**n)*(1-((4*MC**2)/(Kc*(1-MC**2)))*P*101325/(R*T))*(GH*np.pi*D**2)/4) #methane conversion
    
    return[dMCdl,dPdl,JG,GH]
    
Initial=[0,57.8,0.10992158,0.241]
print(odes(Initial=Initial,l=0))
l=np.linspace(0,14.3,144)     
    
Data=odeint(odes,Initial,l) 
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots() 
ax2 = ax1.twinx() 
ax1.plot(l, Data[:,0],label='Methane conversion', color="b") 
ax1.plot(l, Data[:,3],label='Gas holdup',color="g") 
ax2.plot(l,Data[:,1],label='Pressure',color='r')
```

Comment: Which figure in the literature you are referring to? Could you also refer to the ODES from the literature which you have defined above? The coding looks okay, maybe you should write the correct equations for `P` and `GH` in the system (like `dPdl` and `dGHdl`) as they affect `dMCdl` which should give a much better result.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out Muhammad. I am referring to Fig. 6 and to be specific the black line defining the methane conversion (even though it uses the other two lines as input). Previously I used the formulas for P and GH but they let in worse results.

Ofcourse I can try that again however that was quite hard to understand for me. Due to the fact JG is the input for GH but is not dependent on L. The formula looks as followed: JG = 4*feed*(1+MC)/(np.pi*D**2)*(R*T/(P*101325)) and demands input from MC and P. Any idea how to apply this formula in a ODE system?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question with equations for `dPdl`, `dGHdl`, and `dJGdl`? or share your try (as you said you implemented them and the result was bad) so I can check If I can help?